# ModelAndView returns source code with "text/plain" type

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

my source

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView mainPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("uploadPage");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
}
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

but when executed "mainPage method", jsp page look like source code with "text/plain" type, instead normally page...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        <c:out value="${msg}" />
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

help
[image]

Comment: But from what I can see `contentType="text/html`! I can't see `"text/plain"`

Comment: I updated post, added screenshot

Comment: Can you provide the web.xml?

Comment: I provided the web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it, I think. Change the

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to either this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Whichever works for you. Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836641/spring-jsp-page-not-evaluated).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your page is returned from server as plain resource file. It means Spring isn't called at all and your file probably misses .jsp extension.
First of all check your web.xml to see if DispatcherServlet is mapped correctly to take your URL. If not sure, just put

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Second, check your beans configuration does it have proper viewResolver bean.